Multiresolution problem

I'm using a translator.
The first picture is the situation I am currently experiencing. The tip of the tail looks like it has been torn into pieces and is a mess.
The second is my model's vertices (I'm not familiar with Blender so I don't know the exact name, sorry). It looks fine, but why does it look terrible in view port mode when I use the multiresolution modifier?
After deleting and adding the multiresolution modifier again, this problem went away, but all the sculpting I did for 7 hours is gone. Is there a way to prevent this problem and prevent the sculpting I did from disappearing?
Blender file

It looks like you modified the geometry after sculpting with the multires modifier. But the modifier only works with the original geometry.

Yes That's Right So, is there a way to solve this problem without scalping disappearing?

you must have messed your sculpt, next time make sure that you save some versions of your work in progress so that you're able to come back to the previous one in case of problem
